# Joda DateTimeFormat acting different in several devices (Android)

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

I am trying to format a date with Joda time library but my problem is that it behaves different depending in which device it is executed. This is my code:

```
public static String parseDate (String date)
{
    final String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd, ";
    final String hourPattern = "HH:mm";

    DateTimeParser[] parsers = { 
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").getParser()};

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append( null, parsers).toFormatter();

    String daux = "";
    try
    {
        DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(date);
        String pubDate = dt.toString(datePattern);
        String pubHour = dt.toString(hourPattern);
        daux = pubDate + "kl " + pubHour;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return daux;
}
```

The date "Tue, 24 Apr 2012 11:06:19 GMT" it is formatted correctly in a nexus 4 but it raises an exception when executed in a Samsung GS2. I dont know really what it could be.

The exception is:

```
01-22 15:21:05.160: W/System.err(11718): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 20 Jan 2013 23:27:00 GMT"
01-22 15:21:05.160: W/System.err(11718):    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
01-22 15:21:05.160: W/System.err(11718):    at com.fotbollskanalen.parser.DateParser.parseDate(DateParser.java:150)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely facing locale specific issues in parsing.

From [DateTimeFormatter.forPattern()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern%28java.lang.String%29) javadoc:

> The format may contain locale specific output, and this will change as you change the locale of the formatter. Call DateTimeFormatter.withLocale(Locale) to switch the locale. For example:
>
> `DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withLocale(Locale.FRANCE).print(dt);`

*UPD*

You should change the line to:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append( null, parsers).toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: The thing is that the date it is retrieved from a web service so which locale should be used then?

Comment: @Jatago that depends on the locale that's used by the web service to format dates. From the sample date you provided it seems to be `Locale.ENGLISH`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I tried with Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.UK, Locale.US and none of them helped... One thing I don't understand is why it is device dependent?

Comment: Ok, if I change the language of the device (per example spanish, before was in english) it doesn't work. Any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: @Jatago how did you tried? (See my edit). The locale is device dependent since the user can change the device's language which would change the default locale as well.

Comment: @pingw33n Your suggestion helps me to fix a crash happens when parsing "25/10/2013 7:17:08 PM" on users' phones with Asian languages. The error is: Invalid format: "25/10/2013 7:17:08 PM" is malformed at "PM".